# How do I write a branchless std::vector scan?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, conditional-statements

I want to write a simple scan over an array. I have a `std::vector<int> data` and I want to find all array indices at which the elements are less than 9 and add them to a result vector. I can write this using a branch:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    if (data[i] < 9)
        r.push_back(i);
```

This gives the correct answer but I would like to compare it to a branchless version.

Using raw arrays - and assuming that `data` is an int array, `length` is the number of elements in it, and `r` is a result array with plenty of room - I can write something like:

```
int current_write_point = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
    r[current_write_point] = i;
    current_write_point += (data[i] < 9);
}
```

How would I get similar behavior using a vector for `data`?

Comment: `data[i] < 9` is typically a branch at assembly level (although it is surely a better candidate for some `cmov` magic compared to `push_back`, which surely isn't)

Comment: How and why is the second solution better than first?

Comment: I'd expect the `current_write_point +=` line to produce the same code as `if (data[i] < 9) { current_write_point++; }`

Comment: @DimChtz I think that's what he's trying to find out -- he wants to compare the code generated by the two methods.

Comment: Have you profiled `std::partition()` followed by `std::copy()` at the split point?

Comment: @DimChtz: if you know in advance the maximum size *and* the compiler is smart enough to kill the potential branch for the <1 it will run quite a bit faster. If you are doing this in an inner loop of a complicated algorithm with a lot of elements it's stuff that can pay off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see with the actual [compiler output](https://godbolt.org/g/yB0bSg):

```
auto scan_branch(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  std::vector<int> res;
  int insert_index = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (v[i] < 9)
    {
       res.push_back(i);
    } 
  }
  return res;
}
```

This code clearly has a branch at 26th line of [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/g/yB0bSg). If it's greater than or equal to 9, it just continues with the next element, however in the event of lesser than 9, some horrible amount of code executes for the push_back and we continue. Nothing unexpected.

```
auto scan_nobranch(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  std::vector<int> res;
  res.resize(v.size());

  int insert_index = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
  {
    res[insert_index] = i;
    insert_index += v[i] < 9;
  }

  res.resize(insert_index);
  return res;
}
```

This one, however, only has a conditional move, which you can see in the 190th line of the [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/g/yB0bSg). It looks like we have a winner. Since conditional move cannot result in pipeline stalls, there are no branches in this one (except the for condition check).

Comment: Can you please post the disassembly in the answer itself? Thanks :)

Comment: @Rakete1111, sure, but the godbolt color matches the actual lines of c++ code and assembly code, which is much easier to understand in my opinion.

Comment: You can leave the link, but if sometime in the future the link goes dead, the answer is incomplete :)

Comment: What were your compiler settings?  Is the loop unrolled?  Is `v.size()` replaced by a constant?

Comment: And now for the results... how much faster is the second version?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::copy_if(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::back_inserter(r));
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could just resize the vector beforehand and keep your algorithm:

```
// Resize the vector so you can index it normally
r.resize(length);

// Do your algorithm like before
int current_write_point = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
    r[current_write_point] = i;
    current_write_point += (data[i] < 9);
}

// Afterwards, current_write_point can be used to shrink the vector, so
// there are no excess elements not written to
r.resize(current_write_point + 1);
```

---

If you wanted no **comparisons** though, you can use some bitwise <strike>and boolean operations with short-circuiting</strike> to determine that.

<strike>First, we know that all negative integers are less than 9. Secondly, if it is positive, we can use the bitmask to determine if an integer is in the range 0-15 (actually, we'll check if it's NOT in that range, so greater than 15). Then, we know that if the result of subtracion of 8 from that number is negative, then the result is less than 9:</strike>
Actually, I just figured a better way. Since we can easily determine if `x < 0`, we can just subtract `x` by 9 to determine if `x < 9`:

```
#include <iostream>

// Use bitwise operations to determine if x is negative
int n(int x) {
    return x & (1 << 31);
}

int main() {
    int current_write_point = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        r[current_write_point] = i;
        current_write_point += n(data[i] - 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `current_write_point` to shrink the `vector` it afterwards.

Comment: There are still 2 compares:  `(data[i] < 9)` and `i < length`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well, I'm just giving OP a way to use a vector with his algorithm, as he/she wondered how to do that. As far as I understood, OP wants to compare this kind of code to the code with an if

Comment: @ThomasMatthews comparisons are not branches.

Comment: @NicolBolas, but as far as I see, his second snippet doesn't contain any branch, therefore he seems to be aware of that? Even the title says so...

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: Sorry, I got confused as to who said what.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Added version without the comparison with 9

Comment: @Byteventurer, the problem is not comparison! Those bitwise operations may very well be slower than just comparing directly against 9.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR sure, but I think it's branchless? Isn't that what we are looking for? Though the comparison one should be branchless too. Just wanted to get rid of some of the downvotes, as I don't know what the reason for them really is

Comment: Calling a function usually requires a branch unless the compiler can optimize it and is told do so.  The idea is to remove all branches and function calls.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: Please translate a compare into assembly language.  All the assembly languages I've seen require a compare instruction and a jump (branch) based on the condition code.  Thus there is a branch.  Take the code in this answer and look at the assembly language. The ARM series is an exception, as their instructions (in Supervisor mode), can conditionally execute.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Fatih BAKIR did provide a disassembly in his answer

Comment: @ThomasMatthews As for the function call, it can be taken out, and probably is inlined