# Array Indices vs Array Elements

Tags: c++, c, arrays, indices

This is a sort of meta-question related to this question: [How do I write a branchless std::vector scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798841/how-do-i-write-a-branchless-stdvector-scan).

The question originally stated (emphasis mine):

> I have a `std::vector<int> data`; and I want to find all the **array
>   indexes** that are less than 9 and add them to a result vector.

Then I edited it to:

> I have a `std::vector<int> data`, and I want to find all **elements** that
>   are less than 9 and add them to a result vector.

And then another user edited it to:

> I have a `std::vector<int> data` and I want to find all **array indices at
>   which the elements** are less than 9 and add them to a result vector.

I flagged it for a moderator to revert this, stating:

> I reworded this question ([stackoverflow.com/posts/38798841/revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38798841/revisions))
>   with the main goal of replacing "array indexes" with "elements", since
>   that is what's actually being asked - and referring to
>   "indexes/indices" in this context causes some confusion. However, user
>   Aconcagua has overturned this crucial part of my edit. It's my belief
>   that his latest edit should be rolled back.

and it was declined with reason:

> Aconcagua's edit is correct; the user is collecting array indicies,
>   not the array elements themselves

.

Now, I don't quite understand what the moderator says - "the user is collecting array indicies". The way I see it, an index is the location of an element within an array. For example, in the C language:

```
char array[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
int index = 1;
char element = array[index];
printf('%c', element);
```

I simply don't see how, or why, he would be collecting "indices" instead of "elements". Can someone clarify this so I can really understand it?

Comment: Instead of editing the question, you should have left a comment asking the OP to clarify the question. Only the OP knows what s/he is trying to find. So neither you nor anyone else should be editing the question. If it needs fixing, let the OP fix it.

Comment: @user3386109 You do have a point, but editing other people's posts for clarification is a valid measure. Specially when our requests are ignored by OP. We've all seen this. And as another moderator once told me: *"the (active) OP can revert it if it he wants to "*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example code at the top of the linked question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    if (data[i] < 9)
        r.push_back(i);
```

Notice that `i` is being added to the vector, *not* `data[i]`.

`i` is the index of the interesting element, and is what is being stored, not the value stored at `data[i]`, which is the element in the `data` vector.

Comment: Damn! Right indeed. I realize now that there was a total confusion on MY part. Thank you for taking the time to answer this "kinda dumb-ish" question.